# Menu command name for adjusting brightness

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, display

I'm trying to change the Increase brightness key from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F7</kbd>.

In order to do that, I went to `System Preferences` and tried to make a custom shortcut, but I realized that I didn't know the menu command name for adjusting brightness, if it exists at all.

I tried "Increase Brightness," "Brightness Up," "Increase Display Brightness," all that stuff but none of them worked.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't made this easy (or if they have, I've missed it).

The only way that I know to do this is with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/).

You may need to disable the iTunes media keys on your Mac keyboard:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

And then you can use Keyboard Maestro’s *Device Key* option (for some reason the "Hot Key" didn't work.) Press the key that you want to use.

[image]

Comment: Bummer. If Keyboard Maestro can do it, surely there must be a way to do it manually. (And I gotta say, paying $36 doesn't seem too fun either)

Comment: There are a ton of things that Keyboard Maestro can be do, and usually do easier than other ways. It's one of the first apps that I install after setting up a new Mac. Well worth the price.